# aws sam ECR tag name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless

i tried to use aws sam(AWS Serverless Application Model) to create function and ecr,but sam deploy will rename my docker images and push it, how can i custom ecr tag name in aws sam something like template.yml and samconfig.toml

```
version = 0.1
[default]
[default.deploy]
[default.deploy.parameters]
stack_name = "dev"
s3_bucket = "aws-sam-cli-abc"
s3_prefix = "dev"
region = "us-east-1"
confirm_changeset = true
capabilities = "IAM"
image_repositories = ["InferenceFunction=???.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/???:latest"]
```

i want change tage use latest